# Create Azure AD integrated SQL Server connection in an ARM template

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

It looks like we are now able to authenticate with Azure AD with a SQL Server connector in a Logic App, which is great!

[Here is a screenshot of the new connector dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb87i.png).

My problem is when I go to change the name of this connector via an ARM template, I no longer have the Azure AD Integrated option when I select 'Edit Api Connection' for that connection in Azure Api connection blade, it looks like the SQL Server authentication connection.

[Api Connection with Azure AD Integrated when creating the connection from a Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kdym.png)

[Api Connection when creating it from an ARM template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXF4N.png)

From what I can see and have tried, when I export the templates from Azure they look identical.  Here are the examples.

Template Export from Azure AD Integrated Connection:

```
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('azure_ad_authenticated_connection')]",
            "location": "<valid_location>",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "{<db_name>} {<db_server_name>}",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/<location>/managedApis/', parameters('connections_sql_name'))]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Template Export from a SQL Server authenticated connection:

```
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('sql_server_auth_connection')]",
            "location": "<valid_location>",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "<display_name>",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/<valid_location>/managedApis/sql')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Has anyone been able to successfully create an Azure AD Integrated connection from an ARM template?

Comment: There's related azure feedback item on the uservoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/40651912-allow-azure-ad-integrated-authentication-for-sql-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's to become crazy!

**When Azure exports an ARM template it never includes the parameters that have to be kept secure.** Therefore you end with an ARM template that is incomplete.
In your case you have to add

```
"parameterValueSet": {
  "name": "oauth",
  "values": {}
}
```

The complete template is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "sql_Connection_Name": {
      "defaultValue": "sqlConnectionWithOAuth",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "sql_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "defaultValue": "sql Connection with OAuth",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "logicAppLocation": {
      "defaultValue": "westeurope",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('sql_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('sql_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/sql')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
        },
        "parameterValueSet": {
          "name": "oauth",
          "values": {}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And for further needs, you can use **ARMclient** to figure out the missing parameters. For **sql** api connection:

```
armclient.exe get https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/Microsoft.Web/locations/{LogicAppLocation}/managedApis/sql?api-version=2016-06-01
```

you'll get a long json description that includes the '**oauth**' parameter:

```
"name": "oauth",
"uiDefinition": {
  "displayName": "Azure AD Integrated",
  "description": "Use Azure Active Directory to access your SQL database."
},
```